# Adding facebook like button to Android app to redirect to a facebook fan page

Tags: android, facebook-like

I am working on an android app and would like to add a facebook like button, that when clicked, redirects the user to the apps fan page on facebook, is there a way to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) that uses facebook like button as image and [set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) its [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to your own implementation that [starts activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) with [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) thats action is [ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) and [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) your facebook like page. That would look something like this:

```
ImageButton img = new ImageButton(this);
//set img's image to the fb like image

img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://..."));
        startActivity(open);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should use `ImageButton` instead. And you need to call `startActivity()`. Either make the `Intent open` global, or use the `Activity` class `this` to start the new activity.